# How can I make a border of type "double" in CSS with gradient?

Tags: css, border, gradient

I know I can make gradient solid borders with `border-image`, but how to make it work for double borders too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it with `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements. see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toc1aq0f/)

```css
.gradient-box{
    margin: 40px auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #131313;
   border: 10px solid transparent;
   -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
   -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
   border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
   border-image-slice: 1;
 }

div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
   -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
   -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
   border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
   border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-box"></div>
```